# peak finding algorithm error in python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to implement peak finding algorithm in Python 2.7. The program intends to find the index of the peak element. A peak element is defined as an element that is not smaller than its immediate neighbors(In case of first and last elements,only one side is checked).My code always prints "None" irrespective of the input. Please look in the code:

```
def peak(L,l,r,n):
    if l<r:
        m = l + (r-l)//2
        if L[m] < L[m+1] and m < n:  # n is the length of the array L
            return peak(L,m+1,r,n)
        elif  m > 0 and L[m] < L[m-1]: # l and r are left and right bounds of
            return peak(L,l,m-1,n)     # the array
        else:
            return m
```

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ I am not the down-voter, but i think the down-vote is because of the indentation

Comment: @U8-Forward we can edit question and fix indentation if OP didn't realize that , no need to fast down vote specially with out mention the problem.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ Yeah i know that i don't particularly think it should be down voted

Comment: Can you show what input you call the function with?

Comment: remark: Besides the problem with returning `None`, which is answered below, i don't think your algorithm works quite as expected

Comment: @ChukUltima L=[1,2,4,2,3,4,5,4,2,1]

Comment: @Snowbunting I think the algorithm is fine. I implemented the same logic and wrote the code in C++ and tested it for multiple cases and it returned correct answer all the times. If you have any specific test case please tell.

Comment: @SouravSahoo you have to test first `m < n` and then the other, or you might get `IndexError`. Otherwise it is fine, sorry not paying too much attention^^

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively increasing `l` or decreasing `r`, but since yout first `if` has no `else` it will at some point return `None`.

Your code is equivalent to

```
def peak(L,l,r,n):
    if l<r:
        ... #recursion
    else:
        return None
```